# Creating a Christmas Tree with proper spacing with the trunk and base under the leaves

Tags: java, nested-loops

I just can't seem to space the trunk and base of my christmas tree. The trunk and base are a fixed value and they have to be centered for any values given for the tree leaves.

I tried doing this

```java
public class Proj01_xmasTree {
    //christmas time scott r portdog45680-41fasda
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //int gives amount of lines to print
        int size = 4;
        int treeWidth = size * 2 - 1;
        tree1(size);
        tree2(size);
        tree3(size);
        trunk(1);
        base(1);
    }
    
    public static void tree1(int size){
        // "i" starts on different stars
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            //4 + 1 + 0 = 5. 4 + 1 - 1 = 4, etc..
            for (int j = 0; j < size + 1 - i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
                //stars 1,3,5,7. i*2 + 1. 0 + 1 = 1. 
                for (int k = 0; k < i*2 + 1; k++){
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static void tree2(int size){
        //"i" starts on different stars
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
            //4 + 1 + 0 = 5. 4 + 1 - 1 = 4, etc..
            for (int j = 0; j < size + 1 - i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
                //stars 1,3,5,7. i*2 + 1. 0 + 1 = 1. 
                for (int k = 0; k < i*2 + 1; k++){
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static void tree3(int size){
        //"i" starts on different stars
        for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++){
            //4 + 1 + 0 = 5. 4 + 1 - 1 = 4, etc..
            for (int j = 0; j < size + 1 - i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
                //stars 5,7,9,12 
                for (int k = 0; k < i*2 + 1; k++){
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static void trunk(int treeWidth){
        int spacing = (treeWidth - 2) / 2;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < spacing; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
    
    public static void base(int size){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < size/2; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
    ***
   *****
  *******
   *****
  *******
 *********
*
*
***
```

Desired output:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
    ***
   *****
  *******
   *****
  *******
 *********
     *
     *
    ***
```

(note: the trunk and base are separate methods. they have to be fixed like that for any of the leaves, please keep that in mind.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the `trunk` and `base` functions as follows (`tree1`, `tree2` and `tree3` functions are not changed).

```
private static void trunk(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}

private static void base(int size) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

For the `trunk` function, the number of initial spaces required is same as the value of `size + 1` and for the base, it is `size`.

Also now all functions work based only on the `size` parameter

```
int size = 4;
tree1(size);
tree2(size);
tree3(size);
trunk(size);
base(size);
```